# Proactive Messages to MS Team User (Private Chat)

Tags: microsoft-teams

I am trying to send a message to the user using Graph API but I am getting 401 error through postman.

Is it possible to send proactive message to Microsoft Teams Users via Graph API?

Comment: Please take a look at [Proactively Install app using Graph API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages#proactively-install-your-app-using-graph). Let me know if you need any help on it.

Comment: Is it possible to send message without using Microsoft.Bot.Connector.Teams. I want to send message directly via Graph API something like this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-post-messages?view=graph-rest-beta&tabs=http